# Вылетает приложение при нажатии на TextView для прехода на другое активити

Tags: java, android

`2019-03-13 16:12:57.628 1285-1285/com.example.tt E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.tt, PID: 1285
    android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.tt/com.example.tt.RegisterActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
        at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:2005)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1673)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4586)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:767)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4544)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:754)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4905)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4873)
        at com.example.tt.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:54)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6597)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6574)
        at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:778)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25885)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)`

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

TextView tv1, edit3;
Typeface s1, ed1, ed2;
EditText edt1, edt2;
Button btn;
final String TAG = "MainActivity";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.kirov_state);
    edt1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtt1);
    edt2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtt2);
    btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Login);
    btn.setOnClickListener(this);
    ed1 = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "Raleway-Thin.ttf");
    ed2 = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "Raleway-Thin.ttf");
    s1 = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "Raleway-Regular.ttf");
    tv1.setTypeface(s1);
    edt1.setTypeface(ed1);
    edt2.setTypeface(ed2);
    Typeface btn1 = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "Raleway-Thin.ttf");
    btn.setTypeface(btn1);

    edit3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.registt);
    edit3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), RegisterActivity.class);
            startActivity(in);
        }
    });



}
private boolean emptyValidate(EditText edt2, EditText edt1){
    String user = edt2.getText().toString();
    String password = edt1.getText().toString();
    return (user.isEmpty() && password.isEmpty());
}
String password = "";
public void onClick(View v) {

    final String user = edt2.getText().toString();
    password =  MD5.encrypt(edt1.getText().toString());

    HashMap<String, String> loginData = new HashMap<>();
    loginData.put("user", user);
    loginData.put("password", password);

    PostResponseAsyncTask loginTask = new PostResponseAsyncTask(this, loginData, new AsyncResponse() {
        @Override
        public void processFinish(String s) {
            Log.d(TAG, s);
            if(s.contains("LoginSuccess")){
                SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("loginData", MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
                editor.putString("user", user);
                editor.putString("password", password);
                editor.commit();
                Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Main2Activity.class);
                startActivity(in);
            }
            else{
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Something went wrong. Cannot login.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });
    loginTask.setExceptionHandler(new ExceptionHandler() {
        @Override
        public void handleException(Exception e) {
            if(e != null && e.getMessage() != null){
                Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    });
    loginTask.execute("http://recognized-vessel.000webhostapp.com/login.php");
}
}
```

Comment: В чем проблема написано в сообщении об ошибке. Вы уже прочитали его? Что там написано?

Comment: после нажатия приложение просто крашится

Comment: Это уже понятно. В самом первом предложении вы написали, что "выдает ошибку". Вот ее и читайте. Никакое приложение не крашится просто так.

Comment: плюсую, где код ошибки?

Comment: В ошибке написано что не может найти новую активити. проверь манифест.

Comment: Спасибо всё заработало.

Comment: не проврь манифест, а задекларируйте ее в манифесте